# How do convert this code and my thinking to a functional mindset (Clojure)?

Tags: javascript, clojure, functional-programming

How do I convert this JavaScript code to Clojure?

I am trying to draw a (x,y) world where the cells are on or off according to the fill property. In the example below I am trying to print the rows then columns but my next step is to move the fill property around (up, down, left, right). So, I don't want an answer which wouldn't work if I were not printing the data structure.

My goal is to understand how to think about this problem in a functional way. It was easy for me to solve this problem with mutable state in JavaScript. While working on the solution, I was able to easily reason about how to write the code in JavaScript but when I came to do the same in Clojure, I was at a loss. So, I feel like a good answer to this question would be to help me understand how to think about this kind of problem in a functional way.

I have watched many talks and read a bunch of articles about Clojure and functional programming but when it becomes to writing the code, it's difficult for me to get started.

```js
var world = [
    [{ x: 1, y: 4, fill:0 }, { x: 2, y: 4, fill:0 }, { x: 3, y: 4, fill:0 }, { x: 4, y: 4, fill:0 }],
    [{ x: 1, y: 3, fill:0 }, { x: 2, y: 3, fill:0 }, { x: 3, y: 3, fill:0 }, { x: 4, y: 3, fill:0 }],
    [{ x: 1, y: 2, fill:0 }, { x: 2, y: 2, fill:0 }, { x: 3, y: 2, fill:0 }, { x: 4, y: 2, fill:0 }],
    [{ x: 1, y: 1, fill:0 }, { x: 2, y: 1, fill:0 }, { x: 3, y: 1, fill:1 }, { x: 4, y: 1, fill:0 }]
];

function printworld(world) {
    var out = "";
    for(var row=0; row<world.length; row++) {
        for(var col=0; col<world[row].length; col++) {
            out += "["+world[row][col].fill+"]";
        }
        out += "\n"
    }
    console.log(out);
}

printworld(world);
```

The output looks like:

```js
[0][0][0][0]
[0][0][0][0]
[0][0][0][0]
[0][0][1][0]
```

EDIT: After spending time working through the problems at 4clojure.com, I realized that I was trying to bite off a larger problem (ex. a Chess game in Clojure) than I was ready to solve. Creating the most basic functions at 4clojure.com has been difficult but it's building a steady working knowledge on how to approach a solution using the functional method.

Comment: Are you looking for the equivalent Clojure code or how to start thinking solving it in Clojure way?

Comment: you can do it functionally in js using two named methods to map() the array: renderRow and renderCell...

Comment: Chiron, I am looking to start thinking to solve it in a Clojure way. For sure, better thinking is what I am after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How to start thinking in a functional way?  There is no short cuts and quick answers. You have to invest a good amount of time trying to code in functional way.

You can start by morphing simple algorithms. But it is important to keep in mind that in functional programming you care about data flow, not how to instruct the CPU to do this and that.

It is important to know the core functions in your language. From those core functions, you can start transform you data. Kind of Lego or DNA stripes if you want.

If you are interested in Clojure particularly, then I recommend to spend good time on 4Clojure and [Land of Lisp](http://nostarch.com/lisp.htm).

And Clojure IRC is a wonderful place to learn from Rockstars Clojure developers. Friendly community and helpful for sure.

Always remember: "OOP isn't easy by default and FP isn't hard by default".

Comment: Chiron, thanks for the encouragements in "no short cuts" and the 4clojure resource. I read some of Land of Lisp a while back. People say, "it clicked for me". Most of the material I am finding is duplications of material I have already read. I believe I am struggling because I want my mutable variables and I don't know how to think differently, functionally. How do you ask the right questions when you are confused about the problem? Time to pull out "How to Solve It" once again.

Comment: Chiron, I am giving you the solution because you got at the heart of my question even though I didn't ask it very well (an apology to the other great answers). I have spent several hours on 4clojure.com and it is a goldmine. I am learning a lot and as a bonus I am feeling encouraged in the process. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well the data will look more or less identical:

```
(def world [[{:x 1, :y 2, :fill 0}, {:x 2, :y 2, :fill 0}]
            [{:x 1, :y 1, :fill 0}, {:x 2, :y 2, :fill 1}]])
```

but for the print function you can use `doseq`

```
(defn print-world [world]
  (doseq [row world]
    (doseq [cell row]
      (print (str "[" (:fill cell) "]")))
    (println)))

(print-world world)

;; outputs
;; [0][0]
;; [0][1]
```

and to change elements, `assoc-in` or `update-in`

```
; move the filled cell 'up'
(print-world
  (-> world
    (assoc-in [1 1 :fill] 0)     ; set bottom-right fill to 0
    (assoc-in [0 1 :fill] 1)))   ; set top-right fill to 1

;; outputs
;; [0][1]
;; [0][0]
```

Clojure isn't the best fit for this kind of programming, but it is useful stuff to know.

Edit: as for thinking in a functional way, that's not the kind of skill that can be easily conveyed through a stackoverflow answer. It takes a good deal of writing code and reading other people's code. A great place to start online would be [Clojure for the Brave and True](http://www.braveclojure.com/). The thing that got me thinking functionally was the wonderful [Learn you a Haskell for Great Good!](http://learnyouahaskell.com/).

Comment: d.j.sheldrick, thanks for your timely and excellent response. I'll check back later today.

Answer (score 0):

When trying to get into "the functional way of thinking" it sometimes helps to look at code and think of ways to **separate the separable parts**. In this example there are three logical phases:

- change the data to contain only the filter field
- put it in vector form (with the `[]`s)
- print it nicely

If we seperate these into their own Clojure expressions then perhaps you will be able to reuse one of them elsewhere, or write better tests etc. as opposed to doing both actions in the same pass through the matrix (which is admittedly, slightly more efficient)

```
user> (def world [[{:x 1, :y 4, :fill 0 }, {:x 2, :y 4, :fill 0 }, {:x 3, :y 4, :fill 0 }, {:x 4, :y 4, :fill 0 }],
                  [{:x 1, :y 3, :fill 0 }, {:x 2, :y 3, :fill 0 }, {:x 3, :y 3, :fill 0 }, {:x 4, :y 3, :fill 0 }],
                  [{:x 1, :y 2, :fill 0 }, {:x 2, :y 2, :fill 0 }, {:x 3, :y 2, :fill 0 }, {:x 4, :y 2, :fill 0 }],
                  [{:x 1, :y 1, :fill 0 }, {:x 2, :y 1, :fill 0 }, {:x 3, :y 1, :fill 1 }, {:x 4, :y 1, :fill 0 }]])
#'user/world

user> (defn filter-fill [world] (map #(map :fill %) world))
#'user/filter-fill

user> (filter-fill world)                                                            
((0 0 0 0) (0 0 0 0) (0 0 0 0) (0 0 1 0))

user> (defn vector-world [world]  (mapv #(mapv vector %) world))
#'user/vector-world 

user> (clojure.pprint/pprint (vector-world (filter-fill world)))
[[[0] [0] [0] [0]]
 [[0] [0] [0] [0]]
 [[0] [0] [0] [0]]
 [[0] [0] [1] [0]]]
nil
```

Comment: Pure beauty and elegance! How someone couldn't fall in love with Clojure?

Comment: You could use `mapv` and `comp` to simplify this. e.g. `(defn vector-world [world] (mapv #(mapv (comp vector :fill) %) world))`

Comment: yes, that's much better on the vectors. The main idea in this answer is to show things as separated as possible, so composing them, while better clojure, illustrates that point less well, so I'm leaving the comp out.

Comment: Arthur, thanks for the helpful answer. I appreciate the way you showed how to break the problem into smaller ones.

Comment: Arthur, after spending a bunch of time on 4clojure.com, I see that, "separate the separable parts" is the key. Again thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This sketch generates the states of the world rather than mutating a structure in memory. In Rich Hickey speak, it generates the next value instead of storing something different at the same old place.

```
// world is an object with the world's state
var world = function(tl, tr, bl, br){
    this.state = {topLeft: tl, topRight: tr, bottomLeft: bl, bottomRight: br};
};

// screen is an object with internal state that represents
// the state of the of the world
var screen = function(aWorld){
    this.state = [[{fill: aWorld.state.topLeft},
           {fill: aWorld.state.topRight}],
          [{fill: aWorld.state.bottomLeft},
           {fill: aWorld.state.bottomRight}]];
};

// showScreen is a function in which all side
// effects occur.
function showScreen(aScreen){
    var out = "";
    for (var line = 0; line < aScreen.state.length; line++){
    for (var pix = 0; pix < aScreen.state[line].length; pix++){
        out += "[" + aScreen.state[line][pix].fill + "]";
    }
    out += "\n"
    }
    console.log(out);
}

// here is the heart of functional style programming:
// generating the next value instead of changing
// some existing state
function nextWorld(tr,tl,br,bl){
    showScreen(new screen(new world(tr,tl,br,bl)))
}

// turn off screen
function screenOff(){
    nextWorld(0,0,0,0)
}

// make a forward slash
function forwardSlash(){
    nextWorld(1,0,0,1)
}
```