# Functional Programming and business domain model

Tags: database, clojure, functional-programming, entity, domain-driven-design

Functional programming discourages the mutable state, and qualifies data structures as everlasting values. Variable may be assigned a new value (a new data structure derived from old by pure functions), but the existing data structures should be never mutated. The paradigm has shifted from procedural state machine to modelling the *functionality* as long chain of pure *functions* wired together. Thus coupling in the system is reduced and theoretically it should be easier to reason about and track the bugs.

But the business domain of problems we are trying to solve in web development are naturally object oriented. We are talking about entities and their attributes. An identity and it's state. The state is stored in the database. When we are making money transaction, we are mutating the specific bank account to withdraw/save the money. We are not thinking about replacing the bank account with new one for each transaction. They are mutable objects per se. This state has to be mutated somehow, somewhere. I realize functional languages doesn't deny the state (it's inevitable after all) but favors side effect free syntax which makes the mutating operations feel awkward.

Now, what is the approach of functional languages to target the very object oriented nature of the real world? For example *clojure* doesn't have the concept of class, thus I guess it doesn't have ORM. How would it align to the relational world of enterprise business? Would the paradigm even know the concept called entity? Would it be allowed to mutate such an entity? Or would the functional programming need a shift in style how we store the data too?

This whole functional approach seems so theoretical and contradictory to the real world. How would I gain more insight how all this works in the real world scenarios of web development?

Comment: Your assertion that the ‘real world’ is naturally ‘object-oriented’ and best represented with a mutable model is not a fact, it is only an opinion. Here the creator of Clojure argues that that view is actually totally inappropriate: https://www.infoq.com/presentations/Value-Values.

Comment: Consider the difference between a road map and an engineering diagram for a car. The first is a domain model, the second is a system model. OOP is meant for systems modeling, not domain modeling (unless you're doing simulation systems). Object-relational mappers aim to reinvent the network data model, they're not implementations of the entity-relationship model or relational model. ORMs are basically a 1970s mindset and prevent both good OOP and good relational designs.

Comment: I believe real bank accounts are modelled as an append-only log of transactions rather than a mutation of the balance, so I would disagree they are 'naturally object-oriented'.

Comment: Functional programming would be very suited to domain services - they just call the right functions on your entities but shouldn't contain state themself. There is a place for everything just as not every app is DDD not everything is best implemented using a functional approach

Comment: It looks like you come from an imperative/OO mindset. There is no easy answer, however you can start reading/experimenting with functional approaches. Don't try to translate every line. Maybe start with http://www.lispcast.com/imperative-mindset  and http://stackoverflow.com/q/20402798/1327651
(by the way, voting to close)

Comment: To add up to all that's been said, here's a good presentation to understand functional DDD through Event Sourcing : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7RIT3cBWYIM

Answer (score 8):

It's probably worth while to start from Stuart Halloway's presentation on [Clojure's Time Model](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/An-Introduction-to-Clojure-Time-Model).

Making no promises to do the talk justice: entities have state.  Note that's has-A, not is-A; so we should be thinking about composition.  Conceptually, what we think of as an object is a mutable reference to immutable state.

Now, if you look at this through the lens of Bertrand Meyer's [CQS](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CommandQuerySeparation.html); query support is easy - queries don't modify the state of the object, so they are in effect a pure function

```
result = query(this.currentState)
```

Command support, on the other hand, can trivially be broken into two parts, a query that produces a new state, and a change to the mutable reference.

```
State nextState = query(this.currentState)
{ref-set} this.currentState = nextState
```

As Lee noted in his comment, currentState and history are dual to one another, which is to say, we can just as easily turn the above example around

```
// conceptually, this is still a _query_; we aren't mutating current state
// but are instead calculating a new value.
State nextState = this.currentState.apply(command)
{ref-set} this.currentState = nextState
```

In [eventsourcing](/questions/tagged/eventsourcing), we're a bit more careful about the distinction between the output of the command of the current model, and the history of the changes, so the spelling tends to look more like

```
// conceptually, this is still a _query_; we aren't mutating current state
// but are instead calculating a new value.
Events changes = command(this.currentState)
State nextState = this.currentState.apply(changes)
{ref-set} this.currentState = nextState
```

Taken across the entire history of the entity, you get

```
State state = fold(history, State.SEED)
{ref-set} this.currentState = state
```

> The state is stored in the database.

Almost: *state* is stored in *the database*.

```
State nextState = database.currentState.apply(command)
{ref-set} database.currentState = nextState
```

For instance, Greg Young describes [Event Store](https://geteventstore.com/) as having only 32 bytes of [mutable state](https://vimeo.com/53153270).  Everything else is *write once*.

> This whole functional approach seems so theoretical and contradictory to the real world.

Not at all -- remember, the *past* is immutable; models that allow you to change the past don't align with the constraints of the real world.

> How would I gain more insight how all this works in the real world scenarios of web development?

For starters, look up Greg Young's talks on event sourcing (especially his newer ones; he's been getting more functional over time), and also [Mark Seemann's blog](http://blog.ploeh.dk/).  In addition to everything you can find by Stuart or [Rich Hickey](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/Value-Values).